# std::rethrow_exception and thrown exception type

Tags: c++, c++11

In a library I have a hierarchy of exceptions (`RuntimeException -> RecognitionException -> NoViableAltException`). During execution, a `NoViableAltException` is thrown, which is caught as below and an exception pointer is created from that:

```
try {
   //code that throws NoViableAltException
} catch (RecognitionException &re) {
  std::exception_ptr e = std::make_exception_ptr(re);
  reportError(e);
}
```

The value of `e` is used in other places, irrelevant for this question. In `reportError()` I actually handle the error:

```
void reportError(std::exception_ptr e) {
...
  try {
    std::rethrow_exception(e);
  } catch (NoViableAltException &ne) {
    reportNoViableAlternative(recognizer, ne);
  } catch (InputMismatchException &ne) {
    reportInputMismatch(recognizer, ne);
  } catch (FailedPredicateException &ne) {
    reportFailedPredicate(recognizer, ne);
  } catch (RecognitionException &ne) {
    recognizer->notifyErrorListeners(ne.getOffendingToken(), ne.what(), e);
  }
}
```

and here's my problem: when I rethrow `e`, the `NoViableAltException` branch is not taken, but that of the `RecognitionException` (the last one). That is surprising and I wonder why this happens. I also tried to catch `NoViableAltException*`, to no avail. What is the correct approach to catch the individual exception types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [documentation for `std::make_exception_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/make_exception_ptr):

> Creates an std::exception_ptr that holds a reference to a copy of e.

Unfortunately, *copying* `e` means you get object slicing (which @Mohamad Elghawi points out is also more prominently mentioned later on that page). When you call `std::make_exception_ptr<RecognitionException>`, it will hold a copy of a `RecognitionException`, not any derived class.

But you don't need `exception_ptr` at all here. Even though `reportError` does not have the `try`...`catch` in scope, you can still use `throw;` to re-throw the current exception.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B : A { };

void reportError() {
  try {
    throw;
  }
  catch (B &) {
    puts("caught B");
  }
  catch (A &) {
    puts("caught A");
  }
}

int main() {
  try {
    throw B();
  }
  catch (A &) {
    reportError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn I missed that part of: ... creates a copy of e. That explains it of course. However, what if I want to save the exception for later use (shared between potentially many contexts, which is why I use an exception_ptr in the first place)? It might happen that I want to get the original exception outside of an exception context.

Comment: Use `std::current_exception()`

Comment: std::current_exception() is not available later, e.g. when doing error reporting in the main thread.

Comment: @hvd ["The exception object is destroyed after either the last remaining active handler for the exception exits by any means other than rethrowing, or the last object of type `std::exception_ptr` (\[propagation\]) that refers to the exception object is destroyed, whichever is later. "](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#4)

Comment: Also, ["The referenced object shall remain valid at least as long as there is an `exception_ptr` object that refers to it."](http://eel.is/c++draft/propagation#8).

Comment: @T.C., yes thanks, that was obvious and is fortunately not my problem.

Comment: @T.C. Huh. So even though `std::current_exception()` may store a reference to instead of a copy of the exception object, if it does, then effectively, the lifetime of the exception object must be extended? That's good to know.

Comment: @MikeLischke It's a very relevant comment, it would mean that my concerns about using `std::current_exception()` were unfounded, and you *should* be able to use it. Call `std::current_exception()` in a `catch` block, and you *should* be able to use it for your later error reporting, even if that's outside the `catch` block or even in a different thread.

Comment: @T.C. oh, I'm so sorry, I confused my open questions. Please excuse me, you are of course right, your comments are very relevant here.

Comment: Are you sure it is make_exception_ptr() does the slicing? Because I remember the catch clause creates a static copy of the dynamic exception type object, that causes slicing.

Comment: @Sheen Yes, I'm sure. You're not misremembering, but what you remember applies to catching by value, and the OP is catching by reference.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use `make_exception_ptr`; that's something different (it creates a *new* exception pointer with a deduced exception type, and your code ends up slicing the caught exception object). Instead, you want to capture the [*current exception*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception):

```
catch (RecognitionException &)
{
     std::exception_ptr e = std::current_exception();
     // ...
}
```