# How to preserve original exception type info accross different contexts (e.g. threads)?

Tags: c++, c++11

As a follow up to [my question about problems catching the correct exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249698/stdrethrow-exception-and-thrown-exception-type) from a `std::rethrow_exception(e);` where e is a std::exception_ptr, I wonder how can I keep the original exception information outside of the current exception block?

In a library I keep exception_ptr instances in various places, so that it should (in theory) be possible to get the original exception with all the information it contained e.g. in an error reporting function. The exception pointers are created in a catch clause for one of the exception base classes and hence std::make_exception_ptr only creates a copy of the base type exception, not the original one (this is the trouble I saw in the linked question).

Storing a reference is of course a bad idea (the actual exception object would long be gone). Storing a copy of the exception (via a based type) gives me the same object slicing problem, like when using std::exception_ptr. So, what other options do I have?

Comment: Whatever exception you stick into the exception pointer will be the one you rethrow. Everything is already working as intended. Spend a day or seven writing small test code for yourself and reading documentation; it should all work out.

Comment: In particular, there is no slicing problem ([Demo](https://ideone.com/5NHiSg)).

Comment: @KerrekSB, you haven't understood the question. I have no derived exception type in my catch clause, only a base type. But actually your first comment gave me an idea.

Comment: @MikeLischke You should never catch by value.

Comment: The linked answers talk a lot about std::current_exception. If this is not what you need, explain why.

Comment: Random comment: The usual way to use exception pointers and `current_exception` is in catch-all blocks (`catch(...)`). In that situation, types are never a problem.

Comment: @n.m. there is only one answer linked and it mostly talks about exception type info, not current_exception, which is unrelated here anyway, if you read this question again.

Comment: @KerrekSB, using a catch-all block instead would change the behavior significantly, however, since you would also catch exceptions that are supposed to be handled elsewhere.

Comment: If you used a catch-all block, then those exceptions are not supposed to be handled elsewhere, by definition.

Answer (score -3):

Kerrek SB's first comment brought me to an idea how to tackle that problem. Instead of creating an exception_ptr instance from the catched base type I have now a function that rethrows the exception and uses the known sub classes to create individual exception pointers from them, which I can keep and have the info I need:

```
std::exception_ptr DefaultErrorStrategy::reportError(Parser *recognizer) {
  // If we've already reported an error and have not matched a token
  // yet successfully, don't report any errors.
  if (inErrorRecoveryMode(recognizer)) {
    return nullptr; // don't report spurious errors
  }

  beginErrorCondition(recognizer);

  std::exception_ptr result = nullptr;
  try {
    // We are called from catch() clauses, so we can just rethrow the current exception and catch
    // the original exception type, so we don't lose information (caused by object slicing).
    throw;
  } catch (NoViableAltException &ne) {
    result = std::make_exception_ptr(ne);
    reportNoViableAlternative(recognizer, ne);
  } catch (InputMismatchException &ne) {
    result = std::make_exception_ptr(ne);
    reportInputMismatch(recognizer, ne);
  } catch (FailedPredicateException &ne) {
    result = std::make_exception_ptr(ne);
    reportFailedPredicate(recognizer, ne);
  } catch (RecognitionException &ne) {
    result = std::make_exception_ptr(ne);
    recognizer->notifyErrorListeners(ne.getOffendingToken(), ne.what(), result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This function is then called like this:

```
    try {
      visitState(p);
    }
    catch (RecognitionException &e) {
      setState(_atn.ruleToStopState[p->ruleIndex]->stateNumber);
      getContext()->exception = getErrorHandler()->reportError(this);
      recover(e);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I created that code under a wrong assumption (current_exception and make_exception_ptr do the same -> create a copy). As this is not the case actually the code in this answer is indeed wrong and I keep it only for reference, how **not** to do it.

Comment: This is as wrong as it gets. Now you need to keep information about all of your subclassess in one central place, and update it whenever a new subclass is created. This is an anti-OO anti-pattern. You are better off with a plain old union.

Comment: First: the list of subclasses is there anyway. I haven't created that specifically for this solution. Second: the list will likely never change. Third: just because subclass information is handled in a central place doesn't mean it's anti-OO. Fourth: if you have a better solution please post it.

Comment: @MikeLischke: I notice you've been rather hostile across this thread. Not the best way to encourage people to help you for free.

Comment: I'm sorry if that comes accross that way. I thought I answered the same way as the first comment was made, which appears like unconstructive criticism.

Comment: This looks like a poor solution to patch over a problem with a previous poor solution, not a good solution.  In analogy, imagine someone asked how to return an `int`, and someone said `return new int(7);`  They then ask about how to get `+` working, and as a solution they say "to overload, you need to have a pointer to a user defined class.  So use  `struct tagged_int { int x; friend tagged_int* operator+(tagged_int* lhs, tagged_int* rhs ){ return new tagged_int{lhs->x + rhs->x}; } };` instead of `int`) -- bad code whose only purpose is to deal with previous bad decisions.

Comment: Go back to the previous question.  Examine kerrek's answer.  Notice no slicing occurs if you use kerrek's answer.  Eliminate the need for the above bad code, and in fact this entire question.

Comment: Now after I could come back to this problem I realized you all are right. I assumed std::current_exception() and std::make_exception_pointer do the same, but obviously I was wrong. Hope that explains all the confusion. I'l still keep the answer for future readers to learn how not to do it.